# Data Replication from Mysql to Mysql issue

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I am facing an issue regrading data replication between two MySql database. Two database are situated at two different IP address based system. And it is working properly when testing on local host but when I connect the system with another remote system it is giving this error message:

```
 error in connecting the master @ XX.xxx
```

and error no is 2013. What might be the reason? I am also not able to ping to this IP address.(Firewall is diabled) though i can access any application(php+mysql) deployed on this IP address XX.xxx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error message basically tells you what is the issue at hand: the slave has an issue connecting to the master.

There could be several possibilities causing this, either network issues or setup issues.

Some Advice:

- Check out the network between master and slave. Can you connect from the slave to the master at all (maybe try via command line)?
- Is the replication user setup properly? Does it have the [`REPLICATION SLAVE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_replication-slave) privilege?

It might even be a bit more complicated than this, but first give us something to debug further.

Comment: How to check out network between master and slave? i have tried pinging from slave system to master but it is showing 5 packets transferred but 100% loss.

Comment: ping is one way to do it, but you might have a situation where ping isn't allowed but mysql is. better try to connect via mysql command line, like this: `mysql -h (master ip address) -P 3306 -u replication -p xyz` (if you haven't already). If this results to an error you have to check the network, or consult the guys managing this network.

Answer (score 1):

Try to connect from one host to the other with a normal mysql client using the same properties as the replication user (*mysql -h[other ip] -P[other port] -u[replication user] -p[replication user password]*) and issue normal sql commands (*select now()*). If that doesn't work it's an issue with the firewall or similar. Perhaps apparmour if you are running some kind if Linux.

If it does work  make sure that user has the [REPLICATION SLAVE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-howto-repuser.html) privilege, it won't work without it.

Comment: Well the REPLICATION SLAVE privilege is given. there is no issue with this. i have tried what you suggested.. it is giving following error:mysql -h (master ip address) -P 3306 -u replication -p xyz
Enter password:(then it asked for password and i have tried both password of slave and master)
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '(master ip address)' (110)

Comment: try to telnet to that host on port 3306. If that doesn't work it's a firewall on either machine that's blocking you. Check both machines syslogs / messages to see if you get something there. I know apparmour writes to the logs when it blockes something.

Comment: thanks Andreas, i checked the syslog file it is showing:Dec 31 15:55:02 mss60-desktop sendmail[17947]: My unqualified host name (mss60-desktop) unknown; sleeping for retry
Dec 31 15:56:02 mss60-desktop sendmail[17947]: unable to qualify my own domain name (mss60-desktop) -- using short name
Dec 31 15:56:03 mss60-desktop sendmail[17947]: qBVAQ2NQ017947: from=pl, size=558, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201212311026.qBVAQ2NQ017947@mss60-desktop>, relay=pl@localhost

Comment: Dec 31 15:56:03 mss60-desktop sm-mta[18068]: qBVAQ3mj018068: from=<pl@mss60-desktop>, size=816, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201212311026.qBVAQ2NQ017947@mss60-desktop>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Dec 31 15:56:03 mss60-desktop sm-mta[18068]: qBVAQ3mj018068: to=<pl@mss60-desktop>, delay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30816, dsn=4.4.3, stat=queued

Comment: the error continue.. Dec 31 15:58:07 mss60-desktop sm-mta[18075]: grew WorkList for /var/spool/mqueue to 4000
Dec 31 15:58:07 mss60-desktop sm-mta[18075]: grew WorkList for /var/spool/mqueue to 5000

Answer (score 0):

This provides a detailed description on how to do it with no problems. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html

Comment: Welcome to ! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.